# will object outside while loop be GCed?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, while-loop

```
 public static void TimePublisher(int port)
    {
        var ctx = ZmqContext.Create();
        var socket = ctx.CreateSocket(SocketType.REP);
        socket.Bind("tcp://*:" + port.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var wait = socket.Receive(Encoding.UTF8);
                var timeString = GetTimeString();
                socket.Send(timeString, Encoding.UTF8);
            }
            catch (ZmqException ex)
            {
                Logger.ErrorException("blabla", ex);
            }

        }
    }
```

will the object ctx be GCed, during the execution of the below while loop?
I think there is a reference stored in stack that reference the object, only when the method exit, the stack is cleared thus reference is cleared, only then the object should be GCed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If `socket` maintains a reference to the context that created it, then no.(*)

If not, then maybe. If you're running in a non-debug context, then it *may* be collected while the `while` loop is running - of course, if no collections occur during the lifetime of the `while` loop than it will not be collected.

If you're running in debug, then all local variables are kept alive until the end of the method.

---

(*) Similarly, `ZmqContext.Create` appears to be a static method. If that method stores the values it returns in a static collection of some sort, then it probably still won't be eligible.

Comment: why so, i think there is a reference stored in stack that reference the object, only when the method exit, the stack is cleared thus reference is cleared, only then the object should be GCed.

Comment: @Benny - no, in release mode, the JIT and GC collaborate, so that variables that are no longer referenced in the current method do not act as roots. That's what my second and third paragraphs are addressing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether `socket` holds a reference to it or not.

If `socket` does hold a reference to `ctx` then it won't be GC'd.

If `socket` doesn't hold a reference to `ctx` then it can become available for GC.

If you don't want it to be GC'd then add a call to [`GC.KeepAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx) after the loop.